# Variable not defined when exporting to excel

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I am using a export to excel feature with a php/mysql site. It works fine when I have a set query in the file, the xls document downloads in an instant.

I'm having trouble getting it to work with a custom php variable, as soon as I put a custom variable at the top of the php file so that the query can be modified by the user, it messes up and says undefined variable.

I'm, passing the variable via a html form using the post method, so I can't see what Im doing wrong, could any one point me in the right direction?

The first file is exportoexcel.php, its the query selector, this is then called by the next file.

```
<?php

$VARIABLE="IDNX";

class ExportToExcels
{
    private $host;
    private $dbUser;
    private $dbPassword;
    private $database;
    private $dbTableName;
    private $data;
    private $mysqli;
    private $displayColumns;
    public $excelFileName;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->host = "****";
        $this->dbUser = "****";
        $this->dbPassword="****";
        $this->database="****";
        $this->excelFileName="Report1";
    }

    public function setServerSetting($host,$dbUser,$dbPassword,$database,$dbTableName)
    {
        $this->host = $host;
        $this->dbUserName =$dbUser;
        $this->dbPassword=$dbPassword;
        $this->database=$database;
        $this->tableName=$dbTableName;
    }

    public function establishConnection()
    {
        $mysqli = new mysqli($this->host, $this->dbUserName, $this->dbPassword, $this->database);
        if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
            return false;
            exit;
        }
        else
        {
            return $mysqli;
        }
    }

    public function getAllData($mysqli)
    {
        $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM MTYDE WHERE VARIABLE LIKE '$VARIABLE'");
        if($result->num_rows > 0){
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                $data[] = $row;
            }
        }
        $result->close();
        return $data;
    }

    public function closeConnection($mysqli)
    {
        $mysqli->close();
    }

    public function setExcelfileName($excelFileName)
    {
        $this->excelFileName=$excelFileName;
    }

    public function setContentTypeForExcel()
    {
        header ("Expires: 0");
        header ("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D,d M YH:i:s") . " GMT");
        header ("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
        header ("Pragma: no-cache");
        header ("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
        header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$this->excelFileName.".xls");
        header ("Content-Description: Generated Report" );
    }

    public function getColumnName($mysqli)
    {
        $result = $mysqli->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM $this->tableName");
        if($result->num_rows > 0){
            while ($row = $result->fetch_object()){
                $displayColumns[$row->Field] = ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', $row->Field));
            }
        }
        $result->close();
        return $displayColumns;
    }

    public function generateExcelFile($mysqli , $options=null)
    {
        $this->displayColumns=$this->getColumnName($mysqli);
        $this->data=$this->getAllData($mysqli , $options);
        $this->setContentTypeForExcel();

        echo 'Report' ."\n";
        echo 'Date:'."\t" . date("F j, Y, g:i a") ."\n";
        echo "\n";

        $totalRecord=count($this->displayColumns);
        $i=1;
        foreach($this->displayColumns as $val)
        {
            echo ($i == $totalRecord) ? $val . "\n" : $val . " \t" ;
            $i++;
        }

        $totalRow= count($this->data);
        for($i=0; $i < $totalRow; $i++ ) { $y=1; foreach($this->displayColumns as $key=>$val)
            {
              echo ($y == $totalRecord) ? $this->data[$i][$key] . " \n" : $this->data[$i][$key] . " \t" ;
              $y++;
          }
      }
  }

}

?>
```

Report file, which downloads excel

```
 <?php

$VARIABLE="IDNX";

    include "/exportoexcel.php";
    //Lets create object of class
    $exportToExcelObj = new ExportToExcels();
    //Server Setting
    $exportToExcelObj->setServerSetting("localhost","***","***","***","***");
    //Establish a connection
    $mySQLiConn=$exportToExcelObj->establishConnection();
    //Provide your Report Name
    $exportToExcelObj->setExcelfileName('MEASDATA');
    // Generating report
    $exportToExcelObj->generateExcelFile($mySQLiConn);
    //Close connection
    $exportToExcelObj->closeConnection($mySQLiConn);

    ?>
```

Comment: Where exactly do you try to use that `$VARIABLE` ?

Comment: $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM MTYDE WHERE VARIABLE LIKE '$VARIABLE'");

Answer (score 0):

You have a scope problem here.

What you could do is send your var to the constructor :

```
$exportToExcelObj = new ExportToExcels($VARIABLE);
```

Then in your constructor :

```
public function __construct($var) {
  $this->host = "****";
  $this->dbUser = "****";
  $this->dbPassword="****";
  $this->database="****";
  $this->excelFileName="Report1";
  $this->VARIABLE = $var
}
```

And later on use `$this->VARIABLE` when needed.

Some explanations :

```
$var = 'something';

class MyClass {

  private $classVar = 'something else';

  function showVar() {
    echo $var;
  }

  function showClassVar() {
    echo $this->classVar;
  }

}

$class = new Class;
$class->showVar(); // Won't work, $var is not defined in the scope of your class (and of your function)
$class->showClassVar(); // Works, $classVar is a class property
```

Comment: Tried this, but still getting the same UNDEFINED VARIABLE error :(

Comment: @DannyEng14 If you sent it to the class by the constructor, and if you use it as a property of the class, it should be set. How did you try it ?